# Find all possible values of $ d_{17}$ knowing that $ (d_7)^2 + (d_{15})^2= (d_{16})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $ d_1,d_2 \ldots, d_r$ be the positive divisors of $ n$. Namely, 
>   $$ 1=d_1<d_2< \ldots <d_r=n$$
>   Now if $ (d_7)^2 + (d_{15})^2= (d_{16})^2$ find all possible values of $ d_{17}$

I don't know which tools should I use here. I know so far that all the prime divisors satisfy the condition $d^2\le \frac{n}2$

Patently this tells us that must be always some relationships between divisors of a number $n$ satisfying Pythagorian relation such as $ (d_7)^2 + (d_{15})^2= (d_{16})^2$.

Any hint or help is welcome

Comment: A fine question.   Where did you get this from?   A competition?

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy yes I dont remember which one

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

It is well-known, that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then $60|abc$ so $d_2=2,d_3=3,d_4=4,d_5=5,d_6=6$ and $d_7=7,8,9$ or $10$

**Further Hint**

If $d_7=7$ then $d_{16}-d_{15}=1$, hence $d_{16} + d_{15}=49 \implies d_{16}=25,d_{15}=24$ then $4200|n$ and $d_8=8$ and...

> $10,12,14,15,20,21,24|n$ \to $d_{15} \leq 24$ but it means ,that $d_{9},d_{10},...,d_{15}=10,12,14,15,20,21,24$ and so $9,13 \not | n$ so $d_{17}=28$

Comment: does this really help to get $d_{17}$?

Comment: @GuyFsone Please see further hint with spoiler box included.

Comment: @GuyFsone There will be further cases to consider, to allow for the other options for $d_7$ above, you should reach some contradictions.

Comment: I am also wondering why you started with $d_2=2$ are we sure that $2$ is part of divisors?

Comment: @GuyFsone I believe so, yes. From $d_7^2+d_{15}^2=d_{16}^2$ one can deduce that $4\mid d_7$ or $4\mid d_{15}$, $3\mid d_7$ or $3\mid d_{15}$ and $5\mid d_7d_{15}d_{16}$, hence $60\mid n$. Thus $d_2=2, d_3=3, d_4=4, d_5=5, d_6=6$ and $d_7\le 10$.

Comment: I have never seen the "well known" result, although it wasn't terribly difficult to prove given the statement by using the parameterization of primitive Pythagorean triples by pairs of natural numbers, $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ and considering the primes $2,3,5$ separately.  Are there other approaches to this result?

Comment: As mentioned above, the divisors of 4200 fit perfectly. Just list them in crescent order and check.

Comment: @Aaron I haven't seen or heard of another approaches, I'd be keen to see one though.

Comment: $d_2........d_7$ are not necesary prime and they my not satisfy the Pythagorean relation that is my point .

Comment: If $a, b, c$ are divisors of $n$, that doesn’t mean $abc | n$, so why should $60 | n$?  In particular why should $4|n$?

Comment: @Aaron for 3 and 5 you can use the fact that the only squares mod 3 are 0 and 1, and the only squares mod 5 are 0,1,4, and so in both cases the only way to have two squares whose sum is congruent to the third is if one of the three is congruent to 0. A similar approach gives divisibility by 4, but you have to work mod 8.

Comment: @Macavity Good point - the statement $60\mid abc$ is unnecessarily weak since what you actually get if you try to prove it (and what you need) is that at least one of $a,b,c$ is divisible by 4.